# Dynamic JOIN - ON in LINQ Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq, join

I have a list `collection`, of class `Collection1`  and want to get  a list of **Pin** given the **Name** "N1", from the initial select by name, I should get those pins that ends with ".1" or (".2") then find the other connection in the list which is ".2" or (".1")

the result should be a list similar to this

```
R1.1  
NoUse1.10  
L1.2  
R1.2  
NoUse1.19  
C1.2  
C1.1  
NoUse2.3  
L1.1  
NoUse2.11
```

Im only getting this

```
R1.1  
NoUse1.10  
L1.2  
R1.2  
L1.1
```

is there a way how to programatically update the JOIN - ON in LINQ?
Thank You

here is my code

```
Public Class Form1

Private Property connCompsNetsSel As Object
Private Property Result As IEnumerable(Of String)

Private Property Result2 As IEnumerable(Of String)

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim collection As New List(Of Collection1)
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N1", "R1.1"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N1", "NoUse1.10"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N1", "L1.2"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N2", "R1.2"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N2", "NoUse1.19"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N2", "C1.2"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N3", "C1.1"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N3", "NoUse2.3"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N4", "NoUse2.6"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N4", "C2.2"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N5", "C2.1"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N5", "C3.1"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N6", "C7.2"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N6", "C7.2"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N10", "L1.1"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N10", "NoUse2.11"))

    'get initial pins from given name
    Result = From cns In collection _
        Where cns.Name = "N1" Select cns.Pin

    'get other pins
    Result2 = From cns In collection _
        Join cns1 In collection On _
            If(cns.Pin.ToString.Split(".")(1) = "1", cns.Pin.ToString.Split(".")(0) & ".2", cns.Pin.ToString.Split(".")(0) & ".1") Equals cns1.Pin.ToString _
        Where cns.Name = "N1" Select cns1.Pin

    'combine Result and Result2
    Dim finalResult As New ArrayList
    finalResult.AddRange(Result.ToArray)
    finalResult.AddRange(Result2.ToArray)
End Sub
End Class

Public Class Collection1
    Private _Name As String
    Private _Pin As String
Public Sub New(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Pin As String)
    _Name = Name
    _Pin = Pin
End Sub

Public Property Name As String
    Get
        Return _Name
    End Get

    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        _Name = Value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Pin As String
    Get
        Return _Pin
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        _Pin = Value
    End Set
End Property
End Class
```

Comment: I'm pretty confused. You want to get pins that have a name of N1. But then you want to get pins that contain .1 or .2? Do you then want to join these two collections of pins together? What about the overlap? You then talk of wanting to get the other connection in the list. I've no idea what you mean by that. Also, please can you explain to me what your if statement  If(cns.Pin.ToString.Split(".")(1) etc is doing?

Comment: Please do a better job of explaining exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: For simplifying, create two properties in Collection1 (pinmain,pinsub) that breaks the pin into separate values, and split them during object creation if you only supply two values (name,pin).  You don't have to, but it will greatly simplify your code.

Comment: Just run two different Linq queries, and union the results together.

Comment: Thank you guys for your time checking this question and sorry for explaining it badly.

Comment: the initial Select should start with the Name N1, then finding all pins with either .1 or .2, with the newly found Pins that, if i found a pin that ends with .1, i will then search the list now using the "other" part of the pin which is now .2, and again finding any pins that ends with either .1 or .2 and repeating the process. That explain why even im selecting using N1,it still shows other pins

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you could provide the result you are looking for given you start with N1.

Comment: @RobertMcKee - from my original post i did mention "the result should be a list similar to this", first 3 items are from N1 R1.2, NoUse1.19 and C1.2 are from R1.1 of N1 ... then using pins with .1 or .2 to find the next pins

Comment: It looks almost like you are looking for a recursive LINQ function.  LINQ doesn't have this internally, but you can simulate it by looping until you don't find any additional records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public result As List(Of Collection1)
public tempresult As List(Of Collection1)

Sub Main
    Dim collection As New List(Of Collection1)
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N1", "R1.1"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N1", "NoUse1.10"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N1", "L1.2"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N2", "R1.2"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N2", "NoUse1.19"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N2", "C1.2"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N3", "C1.1"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N3", "NoUse2.3"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N4", "NoUse2.6"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N4", "C2.2"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N5", "C2.1"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N5", "C3.1"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N6", "C7.2"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N6", "C7.2"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N10", "L1.1"))
    collection.Add(New Collection1("N10", "NoUse2.11"))

    'get all pins
    result=new List(Of Collection1)()
    tempresult = collection.Where(Function(c) c.Name="N1").ToList()
    While(tempresult.Any())
        result.AddRange(tempresult)

        tempresult= _
        (from r In result _
        from cns In collection _
        join cns1 In collection _
         on cns.Name equals cns1.Name _
        where r.PinMain = cns.PinMain _
        AND (r.PinSub="1" OR r.PinSub="2") _
        AND NOT (result.Contains(cns1)) _
        select cns1).ToList()
    End While
    Dim finalResult=result.Select(Function(r) r.Pin)
    finalResult.Dump()
End Sub

Public Class Collection1
    Private _Name As String
    Private _Pin As String
Public Sub New(ByVal Name As String, ByVal Pin As String)
    _Name = Name
    _Pin = Pin
End Sub

Public Property Name As String
    Get
        Return _Name
    End Get

    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        _Name = Value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Pin As String
    Get
        Return _Pin
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        _Pin = Value
    End Set
End Property
Public ReadOnly Property PinMain as String
    Get
        Return _Pin.Split(".")(0)
    End Get
    end property
public ReadOnly Property PinSub as String
    Get
        Return _Pin.Split(".")(1)
    end Get
End Property
End Class
' Define other methods and classes here
```

Gives the output:

```
R1.1 
NoUse1.10 
L1.2 
R1.2 
NoUse1.19 
C1.2 
L1.1 
NoUse2.11 
C1.1 
NoUse2.3
```

Comment: The order of R1.1, NoUse1.10, L1.2 isn't guaranteed, but they will be before R1.2 and L1.1.  If you absolutely don't care about the order, you can remove the Order By clause.  Breaking out PinMain and PinSub isn't absolutely necessary, but it's a better approach.

Comment: thanks Robert,please see my added comment, i need to traverse to the list and get the next set of pins by using the other part of the pin. using N1 in the initial query i find R1.1, now i need to search for R1.2 in the list and find pins that ends again with .1 or .2 and repeat the process

Comment: Updated the answer with a loop

Comment: Robert Mckee Thank you